QML layout and padding working in Qt Design Studio but not Qt Creator with Python
I have the following QML code:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300
    title: "Padding test"

    Frame {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        padding: 20

        ColumnLayout {

            spacing: 10

            Label {
                text: "Section"
                font.pixelSize: 20
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            }

            Repeater {
                model: 4

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 200
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                    border.color: "black"
                    color: "lightBlue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


In Qt Design Studio
In Qt Design Studio, this code works just as I would expect. It produces this:

I am using Qt Design Studio 4.5.1, which according to the document Finding the Qt Runtime Version means that it is using Qt 6.6.2.
In Qt Creator
In Qt Creator, the exact same code produces this:

which is not what I would expect. I am using Qt Creator 13.0.2. The application is in Python, and not C++, and so I am using PySide6, which appears to be using Qt 6.7.2.
The Python code that launches this is in Python 3.12.1 and is:
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Questions

Why is there a difference between these two methods?
Is there something missing in the Python setup that is not loading some component of QML?

There's not a way that I know of to make Qt Design Studio use Qt 6.7, so I have no way of knowing if it's a versioning problem. However, that would be very disturbing indeed. Hopefully there is something simple here. My only guess is that this is a Qt bug or there is some "QML component" I can load into the engine from Python.
Thank you for any help!

I'm getting more and more confident that this is a Qt bug on Windows. I am running the code that generated this small example on Ubuntu now, and the padding works as expected. If anyone has any ideas or confirmation of this being a bug, please let me know.

I have now submitted a bug ticket with Qt. If anyone has any idea on how to work around this, I would be indebted. This is a major issue for me, as my primary development machine is Windows, and so now, I can't have any confidence that Qt for Python using QML works well with Python on Windows 11.
